How to map several folders (e.g `/home`, `/var`) to a different (but the same) partition?
Let's say I'd like to keep /home and /var and possibly several more folders on one single separate partition, but all on the same partition. How should I accomplish this?
I know how I could put all those on individual partitions with the mount command and editing fstab, but how do I do if I want them all on the same partition that is separate from root partition?
So as an example. Let's say I have the root on /dev/sda1 and /home on /dev/sda2. No problems there. If I would want /var on /dev/sda3, that would not be any problem. But what if I want both /home and /var to be on /dev/sda2?
I mean, you mount a partition to a folder, so you could for instance have this in fstab:
/dev/sda1 /
/dev/sda2 /home
/dev/sda3 /var

But I want both /home and /var to be on /dev/sda2 while everything else is on /dev/sda1. I fail to see how the question marked as a dupe, Move home folder to second drive, answers this.

If you're aware of the file-system table, what is your issue?  You control what drive (including network share) directories are on via the file-system directory.  FYI: the system I'm using now has external drives, and network shares mounted automatically (where I specified); and the only change I made was to the file-system table (/etc/fstab); and some permissions for network shares.

I really fail to see how the linked question answers this one.

The linked question might not, but the comment above yours does.

@emk2203 Possibly, but I don't understand it. Could you show how an fstab would look like for my example?

@guiverc: OP asked to reuse one partition for several mounts with implicit while keeping the contents separate. I don't think fstab is the answer here.
It's actually a valid question, and the referenced 'duplicate' is anything but.

This is discussed in meta where people seem to agree that it's not a dup https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20586/why-was-my-question-closed-please-reopen

Are you looking for the bind command/option?

@user68186 Hmmm, that might be it.
